# Swift 5.1 Error: [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build a tuner for an app. I am trying to use AudioKit to print the frequency of sounds picked up from the microphone, but I get this error when the view loads:

2020-12-11 11:18:17.079039-0600 Music App[13872:1105735] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000217ea0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2020-12-11 11:18:17.197369-0600 Music App[13872:1105909] [aurioc] AURemoteIO.h:323:entry: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2

Here is the code for the view controller

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class TunerViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var metronomeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var metronomeLabel: UILabel!
    
    var musicTabBarController: MusicTabBarController?
    
    var mic: AKMicrophone!
    var tracker: AKFrequencyTracker!
    var silence: AKBooster!
    var timer: Timer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        musicTabBarController = tabBarController as MusicTabBarController
        metronomeLabel.text = "\(Int(musicTabBarController!.metronome!.bpm))"
        musicTabBarController!.metronomeLabel = metronomeLabel
        metronomeLabel = musicTabBarController!.metronomeLabel
        
        AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
        mic = AKMicrophone()
        tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic)
        silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        AKManager.output = silence
        do {
            try AKManager.start()
        } catch {
            print("error starting AKManager")
        }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func updateUI() {
        if tracker.amplitude > 0.1 {
            print(String(format: "%0.1f", tracker.frequency))
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func metronomeToggle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        musicTabBarController!.toggleMetronome()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error too.
My fix was to declare (in your case) the variables mic, tracker and silence before the ViewController class.

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

var mic: AKMicrophone!
var tracker: AKFrequencyTracker!
var silence: AKBooster!

class TunerViewController: UIViewController {
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did what you suggested and the app now works on my physical device but it still gets this error when I run it on a simulator. Is there any way to fix it so that it doesn't get this error on the simulator?

Comment: Sorry, for me, it also didn't work in the Simulator.

Comment: Strange to have to make them global to the app.